# Incorrect Output and I cannot figure out why

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Code:

```
    ArrayList<Employer> use = new ArrayList<Employer>();
    ArrayList<String> Alia = new ArrayList<String>();
    int moneyE, moneyF;
    String Alias = "";
    boolean alert, alertF;
    for(int i = 0; i < Filers.size(); i++)
    {
        moneyE=0;
        use.clear();
        Alia.clear();
        Alias = "";
        alert = false; alertF = false;
        use.addAll(this.findEmployerRecords(Filers.get(i)));
        moneyF = Filers.get(i).getIncome();

        for(int j = 0; j< use.size(); j++)
        {
            moneyE += use.get(j).getEmployeeWages();
            if(!(Filers.get(i).getName().equals(use.get(j).getEmployeeName())) 
            && !(Alia.contains(use.get(j).getEmployeeName())))
                Alia.add(use.get(j).getEmployeeName());
            if(moneyE !=moneyF 
            && !(Filers.get(i).getName().substring(0, Filers.get(i).getName().indexOf(" ")+1).equals(
             use.get(j).getEmployeeName().substring(0, use.get(j).getName().indexOf(" ")+1))))          //problem occurs here
                alert = true;
            if (alert = true)
                alertF = true;
        }
        for(int j=1; j<Alia.size();j++)
            Alias+= (", " + Alia.get(j));
        if (moneyE != moneyF)
            Discrepancies.add(new Discrepancy(alertF, moneyF-moneyE, Filers.get(i).getName(),
            Filers.get(i).getSSN(), Alias));
    }
```

I am at the end of my stick. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. This is a bit of the code I am working with to create a virtual IRS. If I remove the +1 at the problem spot, I get an out of bound exception. The problem I am having is with the alert and alertF. The alert status should go off if the moneyE and moneyF are mismatched AND the last name is spelled different between the employer records and the filer. Alerts are shown with the asterisks.

Expected:

```
  *-100, HEATON MARK, 309582302, MCGUIRE MARK
  *-50, FOX CHARLES, 724113610, BOX CHARLES
   +105, MOFFITT DONALD, 206516583, MOFFITT DON
   +100, YOUNG THOMAS, 813068590, YOUNG THOM, YOUNG TOM
   -20, SOMASUNDAR PRASANTH, 138001926
   +5, HORSLEY MARIA, 239984300
   +5, LIANG BO, 743287509
   +5, LIANG BO, 857410861
```

Actual:

```
  *105, MOFFITT DONALD, 206516583
  *-100, HEATON MARK, 309582302, HEATON MARK
  *100, YOUNG THOMAS, 813068590, YOUNG TOM
  *-50, FOX CHARLES, 724113610
  *-20, SOMASUNDAR PRASANTH, 138001926
  *5, HORSLEY MARIA, 239984300
  *5, LIANG BO, 743287509
  *5, LIANG BO, 857410861
```

Comment: You should attach a debugger and step through your code to see where your problem is.

Comment: Post your exception with complete stack trace.

Comment: In that last for loop you initilze `j` to 1, could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code by taking out the repeated calls to the same object, i.e. you have numerous calls to `Filers.get(i)` within your logic. Abstract these out to improve the readability of the code.

Also you have lots of not statements, think about your logic.

Hint:  `!A & !B = ! (A | B)`

Below is a simplified, easier to read version of your code.

```
alert = false; 
alertF = false;
Filer f = Filers.get(i);
use.addAll(this.findEmployerRecords(f));
moneyF = f.getIncome();
String filersName = f.getName();

for(int j = 0; j< use.size(); j++)
{
    moneyE += use.get(j).getEmployeeWages();
    String emplName = use.get(j).getEmployeeName();

    if(!(filersName.equals(emplName) || Alia.contains(emplName)))
            Alia.add(emplName );

    if(!(moneyE == moneyF || filersName.substring(0, filersName.indexOf(" ")+1).equals(
         emplName.substring(0, use.get(j).getName().indexOf(" ")+1))))  //problem occurs here
            alert = true;

    if (alert = true)
            alertF = true;
}
for(int j=1; j<Alia.size();j++)
     Alias+= (", " + Alia.get(j));
if (moneyE != moneyF)
     Discrepancies.add(new Discrepancy(alertF, moneyF-moneyE, filersName, f.getSSN(), Alias));
```

To help you understand what is going wrong, add some print statements like this

```
System.out.println("i=" + i + ", j=" + j + ", fName="+ filersName + ", index= "+ filersName.indexOf(" ") + ", substing= "+ filersName.substring(0, filersName.indexOf(" ")+1));
```

before your logic statements. Also add one for employer name that you are comparing.

---

**There is also this one big problem that this line here**

```
if (alert = true)
```

is ALWAYS setting the alert variable to true - not comparing, as you only have a single `=`. In fact you do not need to compare booleans in logic statements

`if (A == true)` is equivalent to `if(A)`

even better is you can just have a single boolean. Your code is like this

```
 if(/*Condition*/)
      alert = true;
 if (alert)
      alertF = true;
```

and can be replaced with just

```
 if(/*Condition*/)
      alertF = true;
```